# Should i write attribute directives for every element in the HTML in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-directive

So, i'm just learning about Attribute Directives in Angular (5) and how they should be used to change the DOM elements' appearance instead than in the Component itself because we shouldn't access the nativeElement there.

The questions are:

1) Should i write an Attribute Directive for every element in my HTML sheet? Meaning, one Directive with all the changes i want to make for that element (color change, font size, etc) for every element..

2) .. Or should i write them according to the action? For example, a `changeColorDirective` that could be applied to multiple elements.

I need help with this since i can't really find a thorough tutorial about this subject (i would appreciate some directions if anyone knows where i can find that :D).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You don't need to access the native element to change the color or font of an HTML element. All you need is binding. See https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#attribute-class-and-style-bindings and https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#built-in-attribute-directives

Answer (score 0):

Attribute directives can take inputs, similar to Components.
For instance, lets say we want to enhance the [attribute directive from Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) to remove hard coded background color 'yellow' and provide an option to developer to set her own color of choice.

Angular Example from Docs:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective {
    constructor(el: ElementRef) {
       el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
}
```

Its used like below:

```
<p appHighlight>
  Highlight me!
</p>
```

To accept user's choice for color, we can add `@Input()`, say with name `highLightColor`.
Since its value is available only in `ngOnInit` (or life cycle hooks after that), we will also have to move the code that updated the element's background color out of constructor to `ngOnInit` method as shown below

Extended example:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appHighlight]'
})
export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input()
    highLightColor = 'yellow';

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
       this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this.highLightColor;
    }
}
```

It will be used like below:

```
<p appHighlight [highLightColor]="'red'">
  Highlight me!
</p>
```

Similarly, you can additional `@Input()` if your directive has more customization points. In real life, you may not use it to update standard HTML attributes though, but there are other uses possible.